# How do you determine colors for a logo on black and white backgrounds?

Tags: color, logo, branding

How do I choose the colors for a logo in order that it can be used on both black and white mediums? Should I use two different color schemes? Are there other methods of making a single logo which works well in all situations without changing its colors?

A single-color logo (for example, green) which would work well on a white background might be reversed out for occasional use as white-on-black. How do I choose the colors of a **multi-color** logo for that to work in all situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious solution is to ensure that no colour in the logo touches the background: in this way colour contrast doesn't matter. It isn't necessary to change any of the colour(s) in the logo to accommodate the background.

Here's a red logo. It's a single colour, but it illustrates the principle: red on black doesn't really work. The red disappears and the white portion is even more prominent. With a white key, though, both the elements of the logo are noticeable because you are forcing the background to be white.

[image: Logo on different backgrounds]

I've actually used the bordered version here on a dark-coloured noticeboard.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty common practice to make several versions of a logo to go with the different contexts that you'll see the logo in. A "full color," a "black," and a "reversed" (i.e. white).

If you look at the branding guidelines for some of the bigger studios and agencies, you'll see this kind of thing a lot.

http://www.pentagram.com/work/#/branding-and-identities/all/newest/
http://2x4.org/archive/brand/
http://www.wolffolins.com/work